# How to send logs from a grails application to a separate file

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7

I'm deploying a simple grails application with mysql to my test server (Tomcat 7).

I've built the WAR using `grails war` command

How do I configure the logging so that the logs are sent to a separate file rather than being sent to localhost.log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look to the grails [logging documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/single.html#logging). You can create an extra log4j file appender for this in your configuration.

Something like this:

```
log4j = {
  appenders {
      file name:'file', file:'/var/logs/mylog.log'
  }
  root {
      debug 'stdout', 'file'
  }
}
```

(copied from the logging documentation)